# How to prove this matrix identity in lean

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, lean

I am trying to formalize the proof of the following fact in lean:

$$
\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 1 \ 0 & 1 & 1\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}^n = \begin{matrix}1 & n & \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \ 0 & 1 & n\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}
$$

The proof is almost immediately using induction, but I haven't managed to formalize the proof in lean, I tried to prove that matrices are [monoids](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/group/defs.html#monoid), which I think would allow me to use theorems like pow_zero and pow_succ, but I cannot success in proving one_mul or mul_one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to proof this?

Edit:
This is the code I have until now

```
import tactic -- imports all the Lean tactics
import data.matrix.notation

variables M : (matrix (fin 3) (fin 3) ℚ)

lemma lemma1 : ∀ (a : matrix (fin 3) (fin 3) ℚ), !![1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1] * a = a :=
begin
  intro a,
  ext,
  -- No idea how to manipulate this expresion
  sorry
end

def M : monoid (matrix (fin 3) (fin 3) ℚ) :=
{ mul := matrix.mul,
  mul_assoc := mul_assoc,
  one := !![1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1],
  one_mul := sorry,
  mul_one := sorry}

example (n : ℕ):
  !![1, 1, 1; 0, 1, 1; 0, 0, 1] ^ n = !![1, n, n*(n+1)/2; 0, 1, n; 0, 0, 1] :=
begin
  induction n with n hn,
  { -- Should be simply monoid.pow_zero
    sorry},
  { -- Should be simply monoid.pow_succ with simple algebra
    sorry}
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you using `mathlib`? Can you post your code?

Comment: Hi @It'sNotALie. Yes sorry, I am using mathlib. I have added my code.

Comment: When you write `[_inst_1: monoid ℕ]` that means "let's put another totally arbitrary monoid structure on the naturals, unrelated to the one which is already there". So you should remove that from your code. Furthermore your result is harder to prove than you think, because at some point you're using natural division, which is a mathematically pathological function (it doesn't satisfy things like a/p + b/p = (a+b)/p etc because of rounding). So I would coerce everything to the rationals first; then this problem goes away.

Comment: Also, try proving first

```lean
@[simp]
lemma lemma_id : !![1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1] = 1 :=
begin
  sorry,
end
```

Comment: Hi @KevinBuzzard, thank you for your answer and for all the material you have about lean, it is really useful. I have removed the [_inst_1: monoid ℕ] part, and redefined the matrices so that the entries are elements in ℚ, but still I don't really know how to continue from here.

Comment: @damiano, thank you for the response. Honestly, I wouldn't know how to start proving this. In my understanding, the line "one := !![1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1]" was precisely to define the identity element, so I would say that the lemma you propose should be "by definition", but I have no idea how to formalize it in lean.

Comment: `matrix` is already a `monoid_with_zero`, and you don't turn this instance off.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Thank you for your response, but it is still not clear to me how can I prove the above property. How can I use the facts that A^0 = I, and A^(n+1)=AA^n?

Comment: @Gaussian97 There is two different instances going on and it confuses Lean. It's as if you've given `Z` two different `add_group` structures

Comment: I'd recommend coming onto the zulip (leanprover.zulipchat.org), people there will be very able to help, and in a better pace too